# Show that if $\textbf{u}+\textbf{v}+\textbf{w}=\textbf{0}$, then $\textbf{u}\times\textbf{v}=\textbf{v}\times\textbf{w}=\textbf{w}\times\textbf{u}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, cross-product

This question doesn't really make sense to me unless the vectors are all the zero vector. So many things about this don't make sense to me that I fear writing them all down would confuse the reader, so I won't. I'll simply ask: how should I think about this problem? A solution would also be nice.

Comment: Perhaps the second one is $u\times v=v\times w=w\times u$.

Comment: Shouldn't $v\times u$ be $v\times w$?

Comment: Hint: $u\times v = (-v-w)\times v$ under the given assumption.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question, now it should be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\bf u+v+w = 0$ then $\bf u,v,w$ all lie in the same plane, and if placed head to tail will form a triangle.

$\bf u\times v$ has a direction perpendicular to the plane holding $\bf u,v$ and magnitude equal to the area of the parallelogram formed by $\bf 0, u,v, u+v.$  Which will be twice the area of the triangle formed placing $\bf u,v,w$ into the triangle described above.

Any combination of $\bf u\times v, v\times w, w\times u $ will have similar direction and magnitude.  However $\bf v\times u$ will have equal magnitude but opposite direction.

Comment: That seems like a good way to think about it, that they're all in the same plane and thus will have the same perpendicular vector, provided the same orientation. I'll think about that for a while. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $u+v+w=0$ then $w=-u-v$ and so $v\wedge w=v\wedge(-u-v)
=-v\wedge u-v\wedge v$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

> This question doesn't really make sense to me unless the vectors are all the zero vector.

Let me provide you with another two examples of vectors $u,v,w$ such that $u+v+w=0$. Consider $u = (1,0,0)$, $v = (-1,0,0)$, and $w=0$. Also consider $u=(1,0,0)$, $v=(0,1,0)$, and $w=(-1,-1,0)$. Now the question should make more sense.

> how should I think about this problem?

Think about examples like the ones I gave, and try to see whether the conclusion holds, and why. Once you're comfortable with examples you can move on to thinking about the general case and how to manipulate the equations.

Comment: I think you're on to something, however, don't we need three dimensional vectors for the cross product?

Comment: @Chisq Oh, good point -- I'll edit!

Comment: @Chisq Edited! Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @Chisq Good start! So you've dealt with the parallel vectors case. You should now have a better feel for the problem. Perhaps try manipulating the equation $u+v+w=0$ now -- try to get a $u \times v$ term in there.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment before I saw your answer. For anyone reading this in the future, I asked for a hint after drawing the conclusion that parallell vectors  work because they produce a zero vector with which any cross product will also be the zero vector.

Comment: Alright, I'll try and think about that and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Because $$0=u\times(u+v+w)=u\times v+u\times w=u\times v-w\times u.$$
The rest is similar.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\textbf{u}\times\textbf{v}-\textbf{v}\times\textbf{w}=\textbf{u}\times\textbf{v}+\textbf{w}\times\textbf{v}=-\textbf{v}\times\textbf{v}\\
\textbf{v}\times\textbf{w}-\textbf{w}\times\textbf{u}=\textbf{v}\times\textbf{w}+\textbf{u}\times\textbf{w}=-\textbf{w}\times\textbf{w}\\$$